# Better c# HTTP Synchronous calls and timer logic

Tags: c#, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient, synchronous

I am building a c# application (.NET Core 6), calling a Trading Exchange API(WCF) using an `HttpClient`. They have a strict policy of not invoking their APIs asynchronously and they monitor this as well.

I also need to devise a mechanism where I must invoke some of their APIs multiple times a day based on different timestamps. Basically, I need a timer logic.

`HttpClient` offers [`Send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.send?view=net-7.0) which is a synchronous way of calling. I am wondering if there is any better way to make sure I am calling this API synchronously over HTTP and also using a better polling logic.

Comment: I think what they mean by `asynchronously` calling their API is that they don't support concurrent calls. So, you can still use the `*Async` methods (like `GetAsync`) of the `HttpClient` but just make sure you're only making a single call at a time.

Comment: How does the API would know that the caller is sync/async or simply just calling in fire and forget fashion???

Comment: Please specify what you mean by timer logic. If you don't need that data as soon as it gets back to you, you can just save it to a database with a timestamp and call it a day. Simply run your program via task scheduler.

Comment: @PeterCsala Maybe they do not if the client overloads the API then requests will fail which is not what we want. So the recommended principle is to call the API synchronously to avoid failures.

Comment: @Max Database and task scheduler is one way. But I do not want this way. 
I was thinking to use System.Timer or hangfire or azure durable functions..not sure if any better option is present.

Comment: @beast I'd just go with the `System.Timers.Timer` then. It is simple and works. As mentioned in the first comment, you can send your requests async so I'd recommend implementing an event based async pattern. Invoke the pattern within your timer and you are good to go.